# Writing a recurrence relation for a method

Tags: java, recursion, big-o, recurrence, relation

I have a bit of code and need to write a recurrence relation for it.  The code simply calculates 2 raised to the nth power.
Any help is appreciated.

```
public static int two(int n) {

     if (n==0) {
       return 1;
     } else if (n%2 == 0) {
       int x = two(n/2);
       return x*x;
     } else { 
       return 2 * two(n-1)
}
```

Comment: When you say "recurrence relation" you mean something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation ?????

Comment: RE: homework: indeed. So, tjm, what is this for?

Comment: Yea, it's part of a homework. The homework is about big 0 notation, recurrence, etc - that's why the code is so horribly inefficient

Answer (score 1):

The formulation of the function almost is a recurrence relation. Basically, all you need to do is perform a change of variables so the argument to `two` in the recursion is `n`. For example, take the following Fibonacci function:

```
public static int fib(n) {
    if (n==0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n==1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }
}
```

You wouldn't want to use that implementation, since it's horribly inefficient, but it makes writing the recurrence relation easy:

```
fib0=1
fib1=1
fibn+2 = fibn+1 + fibn
```

With the fibonacci example, you don't actually need to perform the change of variables. However, with your `two` function, it will make it simpler to write the relation.

Answer (score 0):

The lines that don't have recursive calls are done in a constant time that we will call c.

```
T(n)=T(n-1)+c if n is odd.
T(n)=T(n/2)+c if n is even.
```

After each recursive call with n odd, the next recursive call we be with n-1 even.
So in the worst case we start with n odd -> n-1 is even -> (n-1)/2 is odd -> (n-1)/2-1 is even and so on...

If for example we start with n=19 then 19 is odd -> 18 is even -> 9 is odd -> 8 is even -> 4 is even -> 2 is even -> 0.

The depth of the recursive tree is about lgn, and since on each level there are c operations then the running time is clgn=O(lgn).